# OnClick drop down text with JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would I create this, with JavaScript, HTML and CSS?

So when I click on something, (in this case, a name of a project), something will drop down, and it will show me information on that project.

How could I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you made any attempts yourself so far? This is a very common thing that can be easily found via Google...

Comment: Do you have a specific problem with code you have tried? If not, you might want to check the "related" sidebar on the right of this page for examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `<head>` of the document:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .details {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".project").on('click', function() { 
            $(this).parent().find('.details').slideDown();
        });
    });
</script>
```

In the `<body>` of the document:

```
<div>
  <span class="project">Project 1</span>
  <div class="details">Some details</div>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="project">Project 2</span>
  <div class="details">Some details</div>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="project">Project 3</span>
  <div class="details">Some details</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I click on the text, nothing happens?

Comment: I just tested the code, and it works fine. Best of luck implementing your solution.

Comment: It works now! I used the link from Google for jQuery. Thank you!

Comment: `$(function() {
        $(".project").on('click', function() { 
            $(this).parent().find('.details').slideToggle(300);
        });
    });`

Would be the best script for this, can click to drop and bring back up!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a div of a class with display: none property in your CSS (to set it invisible in the beginning).
Then you need to create a listener on the div, that triggers a javascript function:

HTML

```
<div class="hidden" id="clkItem">Your text</div>
```

CSS

```
.hidden {display: none;}
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("clkItem").addEventListener("click", function (e){showItem(e);});

function showItem(e) {
e.target.style.display = "block";//Won't work in older IEs
}
```

Comment: It could also be done in JQueryUI with hide() and show() function, which is better (crossBrowser and has effects)