# Drop Down text won't come back up and won't recognize other instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used [OnClick drop down text with JavaScript and HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023829/onclick-drop-down-text-with-javascript-and-html) code to make the dropdown hidden div project. 
But the problems are:
1 - It won't open divs separatelly, all of the "projects" are open at once;
2 - I won't come back up once I click it again.

I made another line of code to make it go up:

```
$(function() {
    $(".project").on('click', function() { 
        $(this).parent().find('.details').slideDown();
    });
            $(".project").on('click', function() { 
        $(this).parent().find('.details').slideUp();
    });
});
    $(function() {
    $(".project2").on('click', function() { 
        $(this).parent().find('.details').slideDown();
    });
            $(".project2").on('click', function() { 
        $(this).parent().find('.details').slideUp();
    });
});
```

And so on... and it goes up as soon as I click it only once, like an animation. It won't stay down and THEN on the next click it goes back up. AND it still gets both down instead of each one separately.

Comment: Can you do fiddle for us?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net - Create one, hit save, and then copy and paste the link in an edit to your original post. This will help us see what you see.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use document.ready to often if isn't needed.

```
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {

});
```

If you bind two events to an element, .. it will be executed if you don't stopPropergation or making "cases".

So you can check the visibility and decide what to do:

```
$( function () {
    $("[class^='project']").on( 'click', function () {
        var $details = $( this ).parent().find( '.details' );

        if ($details.is(':visible'))
            $( this ).parent().find( '.details' ).slideUp();
        else
            $( this ).parent().find( '.details' ).slideDown();

    });
} );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3738Lnmf/

edit:
slideToggle is more elegant :) @Diego López

```
$( function () {
    $("[class^='project']").on( 'click', function () {
        $(this).parent().find('.details').slideToggle();
    });
} );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3738Lnmf/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.slideToggle()` if you want to toggle between show and hide the `div` elements

```
$(function() {
    $(".project").on('click', function() { 
        $(this).parent().find('.details').slideToggle();
    });
    $(".project2").on('click', function() { 
        $(this).parent().find('.details').slideToggle();
    });
});
```